# MVC3 Can't get model back to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller

I have the following **ViewModel**

```
public class RecommendationModel
{
    public List<CheckBoxItem> CheckBoxList { get; set; }

}

public class CheckBoxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

With the following **View**

```
model Sem_App.Models.RecommendationModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
      for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxList.Count(); i++) { 
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CheckBoxList[i].Checked)
      @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CheckBoxList[i].Text)                   
}
<input type="submit" value="Add To Playlist" /> 
}
```

With the following **controller actions**

```
//get
public ActionResult Recommendation()
{
    RecommendationModel model = new RecommendationModel();
    model.CheckBoxList = new List<CheckBoxItem>();
    return PartialView(model);
}

//post
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Recommendation(RecommendationModel model)
{
        foreach (var item in model.CheckBoxList)
        {
            if (item.Checked)
            {
                // do something with item.Text
            }
        }
}
```

Problem is whenever I select some items and press the submit button the model returned has CheckBoxList as empty. How can I change my view to return the list of CheckBoxList? Trying
`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.checkBoxList)` did not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the link as a hidden field: `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CheckBoxList[i].Link )`

Comment: that worked! but now I'm getting CheckBoxItem.Link and CheckBoxItem.Text nulls in my controller any idea why? I updated my controller

Comment: Take a look at the HTML that "DisplayFor" outputs, [this method renders a string that represents the property value.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) When you POST the form, this value is not sent back up to the controller like the other form inputs (and hidden fields).  MVC needs to reconstruct the model from known data in this post... remember that MVC is stateless (goodbye viewstate).

Answer (score 1):

I think you nee something like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
      for (int i = 0; i < Model.CheckBoxList.Count(); i++) { 
      @Html.CheckBoxFor("Model.CheckBoxItem[" + i + "].Checked"  , m => m.CheckBoxList[i].Checked)
      @Html.DisplayFor("Model.CheckBoxItem[" + i + "].Text",m => m.CheckBoxList[i].Text)                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check how the checkbox input name is in the rendered html and also check the form action is sending to the corrent controller/action and the method is post

it should be something very simple..   create the action param as array with the same name of the "name" attribute form check box input

something like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int[] checkName)
{

}
```